# Performance of Flex/AIR applications on ios/Android

Tags: android, ios4, air, flex4.5, flex-mobile

I want to know what are the limitions/Restrictions and the Performance of an AIR application for iOS/Android devices such as ipad2,galacy tabs.
I want to Build an application in AIR which will have charts,a local database i.e, sqlite of size 10MB. 
How will this kind of application performs on ipad2?

Is there any restrictions on memory usage??

Any max limit on the size of sqlite database on ipad?

Is there any issues to create this type of AIR application for ipad?

Any useful videos,blogs ,links on development for air applicaiton for iOS will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find and browse a lot of good demonstrations here:
http://www.youtube.com/user/AdobeADC/videos?query=flex+mobile
and
http://tv.adobe.com/search/?q=Flex+mobile

Particularly I think you might want to watch these two first:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iH3NYeM1SfA&feature=plcp
I only just found this newer one, but it speaks to performance and compatible devices demonstrates a few completed example apps that are currently on markets.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fpVeC7KdkDc&feature=relmfu
This video demonstrates two apps, one with a lots of graphs running on multiple devices. (Running very nicely too =D )

I don't remember having seen any mention of memory or size limitations in all my reading & video watching.  (Which *does* include a lot of videos & tutorials that were **not** produced by Adobe)

There may be a lot technical data in this video, but as of now I haven't watched it yet (~61 minutes):
http://tv.adobe.com/watch/max-2011-develop/how-to-develop-amazing-enterprise-air-apps-for-tablets-and-smartphones/

The apps require Adobe AIR to be installed to run though and because Apple doesn't like Flash/Adobe; AIR has be be bundled into the app itself. As a result, the size of of an app is bigger than expected because Flex built apps can share a single AIR install like on Android & Blackberry.

This is a good example tutorial if you're just starting to learn about it:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A4m0CHos-rw&feature=relmfu

And as of today (5/6/12), Adobe last released version 4.6.1 in December and donated Flex to the Apache Foundation.  You can find lots of details about that here:
http://blogs.apache.org/flex/

Hope this helps =D
Todd